# How to query data in XML column in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, xml

I have data like this in an `xml` column:

```
<product>
   <productID>1</productID>
   <productname>tea</productname>
</product>
<product>
   <productID>2</productID>
   <productname>coffee</productname>
</product>
```

I want to change the value of `productname` to **green tea** where `productID = 2`.

I am using:

```
UPDATE [dbo].ProductDocs
SET ProductDoc.modify('replace value of (/Product/ProductName)[2] with "NewName"')
```

But here it will always change the value in second product. Please tell me how to query with `productID`.

Answer (score 2):

Use predicate expression to filter `product` element by `productID` value like so :

```
UPDATE [dbo].ProductDocs
SET ProductDoc.modify('
    replace value of (/product[productID=2]/productname/text())[1] with "NewName"
')
```

Also notice that, as mentioned in the other answer, XML and XPath/XQuery are case-sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

First thing first, `XML` is case-sensitive and so are the `XQuery` expressions.

Now you could do this.

```
UPDATE [dbo].ProductDocs
SET ProductDoc.modify('replace value of (/product[productID=2]/productname/text())[1] with "GreenTea"')
```

Comment: Agreed about case-sensitivity. But the XQuery will trigger 'syntax-error' because `/[some_expression]` is not valid expression. Furthermore, `productID/@Value` references `value` *attribute* of `productID` element, there is no such attribute in the OP's XML.

Comment: @har07 yeah.. I thought it was a value, fixed it now.